# App gets hanged if I add subview over another view without removing it

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My app gets hanged if I try to add subview over another view controller which is added as subview.

Is there any way to get the view controllers which are in background of view? so that I can remove the view controllers which are in background of a view.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW8c5.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Oze.png)

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Common", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactOptionsDialouge") as! ContactOptionsDialouge
viewController.initializeDataBeforePresentingView(presentConatctUserBasicInfo : userBasicInfo,supportCall: checkAndEnableCallOption(callSupport: matchedUser!.callSupport), delegate: nil, isRideStarted: isRideStarted!)
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
self.navigationController?.addChildViewController(viewController)
```

Here is the code I am using to add view controller as subview. And the other top view controller it comes automatically when the other user accepts the ride using mqtt connection

Comment: show code .......

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code and describe what happens

Comment: I have attached the screen shot of the issue it is happening

Comment: @Paulw11 I have attached the part of code where I am view controller as subview

Comment: @Sh_Khan attached the code

Comment: You should push the new view controller onto the navigation view controller, not add it as a sub ire

Comment: you should do self.view.addSubview(viewController.view) and self.addChildViewController(viewController) not to the navigationController.

Comment: @vivekDas I will try it and let you know if it works

Comment: @vivekDas Thanks for the solution. It works perfectly fine now

Comment: pushViewController is used to show in a separate VC ,  but to add in same vc in addition to the above code you need    **viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code is not crash free. You can use below code if it is relevant:

```
guard let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Common", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactOptionsDialouge") as? ContactOptionsDialouge else { print("viewController is nil"); return; }
guard let matchedUser = self.matchedUser else { print("matchedUser is nil"); return; }
guard let isRideStarted = self.isRideStarted else { print("isRideStarted is nil"); return; }

viewController.initializeDataBeforePresentingView(presentConatctUserBasicInfo: userBasicInfo, supportCall:  checkAndEnableCallOption(callSupport: matchedUser.callSupport), delegate: nil, isRideStarted: isRideStarted)
self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
self.addChildViewController(viewController)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
self.navigationController?.addChildViewController(viewController)
```

Adding below lines of code instead of above works fine for me :-

```
self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
self.addChildViewController(viewController)
```